# How does OAuth 2.0 client credentials work with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, frontend

Please correct me if I am wrong. From my understanding, OAuth is used to authorized different applications. There are 3-legged authorizations which include a user, and there are also 2 legged authorizations which is used between 2 servers for example. If a consumer_secret is secret, then how can my front-end MVC be authorized? I don't understand how you can have safely authorize a client-side application without worrying about a replay attack. Could someone please explain what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 has the [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) which can be used to acquire access tokens within a client-side application. It only uses the Client ID and you won't get a refresh token.